# Download all words from Wiktionary for offline use

Tags: windows, web-apps, offline, scraping, dictionary

I need to learn as much words as I can, so it'd take years to learn these as a non native English speaker. I want to import words from [Wiktionary](https://www.wiktionary.org/), so that I can mark or delete words I already learn. It'll save me time while continuing to learn.

Is there any way to import all words from Wiktionary to use offline?
I need to import all words in an app where I can also edit them.

Operating system: Windows 7

Answer (score 5):

The [FAQ](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Help:FAQ) points to the [Download page](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/).

> http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/ should have the latest copy of the main namespace.
> The cleanest navigation page is http://download.wikimedia.org/. Just download a *-articles.xml.bz2 file and some software to read it.

The [enwiki](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/) page lists all downloads for English.
There are [download tools](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/Download_tools).
Windows software to read that data [can be found here](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps/Other_tools), e.g. the *BzReader offline reader*.

The one thing this does not address is how you can edit your collection to mark entries 'done'. There is a possibility to set up your own wiki and import the data into that, so that you yourself can edit it. I leave it up to you to go through the FAQs for that.

Another approach would be to process the XML files further and extract the data into some tool that you are comfortable with, but your question gives no indications about your experience in this area.

But please note:

> Warning on time and size
>
> Before attempting to download any of the Wikis or their components, PLEASE READ CAREFULLY the time and space scale information below! Because of the size of some file collections (TERAbytes), downloads can take days, or even weeks. (See also our FAQ on the size of the English language Wikipedia dumps.) Be sure you understand your storage capabilities before attempting downloads. Notice (below) that there are a number of versions that are "friendlier" in size and content, which you can customize to your scalability by using or not using images, using or not using talk pages, etc. A careful read of the info below will save a lot of headaches compared to jumping right into downloads.

I think you are underestimating the amount of data that you are dealing with, and the time required to set up all this.

**How about buying a cheap (second hand?) paper dictionary** that you can always carry with you, browse through randomly, noting words of interest (i.e. you may have encountered them earlier and/or not understand them exactly) in which you mark the words you know with a highlighter?

Comment: links are broken

Answer (score 3):

There's a Python script called `dumpgenerator.py` that will export a dump in XML format of any MediaWiki website (such as Wiktionary).

You can then import the XML file to your local install of MediaWiki or to any other application able to parse/edit XML files.

The instructions are [here](https://code.google.com/p/wikiteam/wiki/NewTutorial).

Answer (score 1):

Try My Word List - Make Word Lists - Offline Dictionary app for Android.

It contains over 800,000 English words from Wiktionary.

You can track them, learn as you go, and mark them as mastered.

Free Version: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fortylove.mywordlist.free

Disclaimer: I am the developer.

Comment: "For offline use"... Please share the txt file

Answer (score 1):

**You can also consider using the Websters Unabridged Dictionary**

The online version is from August 22, 2009 
and has a Copyright Status Public domain in the USA.

> http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/29765

Comment: Parts of it may be considered politically incorrect, for example "ABANGA n. Etym: [Name given by the negroes in the island of St. Thomas.]"

Comment: interestingly, googling "abanga st thomas" only produces 1 result that isn't related to the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its possible but its very complicated - You can use mediawiki

here is a german page [link](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Download)
use Google chrome to translate it.(In chrome, at RHS of url bar, near bookmark symbol - star a translator icon should appear)

Comment: Hello, thanks. will I be able to download all contents of wiki and edit them manually? I do want to use these as offline. Or is it to edit these on the webpage directly?

Comment: Editing? i dont know, but You can download any contents from Wikimedia foundation including wikistionary.using Mediawiki. I have tried few Wikipedia contents myself.

Answer (score 0):

[Kiwix](https://www.kiwix.org/en/) allows you to save Wikimedia content to your computer for offline viewing. You'll find precompiled Wiktionary .ZIM files for different languages at this address, among other things: https://wiki.kiwix.org/wiki/Content_in_all_languages

Answer (score 0):

### Viewers

Kiwix uses [ZIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIM_(file_format)) compressed format which is optimized for offline use and more widely adopted for such use. It can be viewed and read by [other programs](https://www.openzim.org/wiki/Readers), albeit Kiwix is the most popular. For mobile devices, [kiwix-android](https://github.com/kiwix/kiwix-android) is the only available ZIM reader, if we're not including proprietary apps like [Livio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=livio.pack.lang.en_US) which uses the Wiktionary data.

### Downloading Wikis

Kiwix offers offline Wikis (including many more outside Wikimedia. E.g: Gutenberg, TED, ArchWiki, etc.) in pre-compiled ZIM format on:

- https://library.kiwix.org/: includes online viewers for downloaded Wiki snapshots.
- https://download.kiwix.org/zim/
- https://wiki.kiwix.org/wiki/Content_in_all_languages

Or if you want to compile latest versions yourself, you can take a look on [mwoffliner](https://github.com/openzim/mwoffliner) tool from OpenZIM

Answer (score 0):

If you want Wiktionary in a structured format, I recommend the https://github.com/tatuylonen/wiktextract project, which offers 6 parsed Wiktionaries and supports hundreds of languages. The downloadable data is here: https://kaikki.org/dictionary/rawdata.html